# helm override list values with --set in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm

How do you override values in a Helm list with --set param in Azure DevOps?

Simple use case in `values.yaml`:

```
environment:
  - name: foo
    value: override_me
  - name: bar
    value: override_me
  - name: baz
    value: override_me
```

In the `deployment.yaml` file I use it like so:

```
        env:      
{{ toYaml .Values.environment | indent 10}}
```

One thing that kind of works, but not really, is:

`environment[0].name=foo,environment[0].value=hello,{...}`

The problem with this override is that it will override the entire list, even if I only want to replace value `[0]`, not `[1]` and `[2]`. 
Also I get parsing errors when I pass url:s or int's (not on localhost, only AZ DevOps) - to overcome that paring error, you can escape it with `\"` - but then the chart is messed up - even though it passes the validation.

[image: DevOps pipe]

So, is it possible to override the env list in my case in Azure DevOps helm deployment? Or do I need to restructure the list to individual `key=value` pairs?

Answer (score 3):

I've got weird experience when doing this, in 2 similar cases in one case it replaces them, in one overrides the whole array. so in the second case what I had to do is this:

```
environment:
- name: v1
  value: keep_me
- name: v2
  value: keep_me
- name: v3
  value: keep_me
- name: foo
  value: override_me
- name: bar
  value: override_me
```

and I was doing this in the Azure Devops:

```
--set environment[3].name=foo,environment[03.value=xxx
```

for the other one I didnt have to do that, it would gladly overwrite only the values I've input. no idea why it did that.

Comment: This is what I am doing, but this will override the entire list, event when I want to keep some values like you show with `keep_me` values :/

Comment: no, notice I'm not giving it `[0]`, I'm giving it `[3]`, in my experience it will overwrite only the values after. so the values you want to keep should be at the beginning of the list

Comment: ah, I see your point. But I bet it will cause problems later on if I were to add more env-vars and forget that the order matters a lot.

Comment: yeah, that is true. other option is to parse the values.yaml directly with something like powershell

Comment: for now, I just changed from a `list` to `key=value` and reference them directly in the deployment.

Comment: well, it confirmed your findings and offered a workaround ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself some variables defined in the task:

[image]

Use a standard set:

[image]

I was using a bash task in a release pipeline pointed at a deploy.sh file which existed as a published artifact.  You need to chmod +x the file for this to work properly.

[image]